# How do I pass array of Bitmap from 1 form to another?

Tags: c#, arrays, bitmap

I usually pass a bitmap image from Form1 to Form2 through this method.

```
//Code in Form1
 Bitmap DataToBePassed;
 Form2 frm2 = new Form2(DataToBePassed);
        frm2.Show();
        this.Hide();

//Then this on Form2
//Inside Public Form2()
Public Form2(Bitmap PassedDataGoesHere);
```

But now, I have an array of bitmap, and I do the same method, it doesn't work. I tried to do this:

```
Bitmap[] ArrayOfDataToBePassed = new Bitmap[size];
Form2 frm2 = new Form2(ArrayOfDataToBePassed);
        frm2.Show();
        this.Hide();

//In form2
Bitmap[] ArrayOfDataToBePassedGoesHere = new Bitmap[size];
Public Form2(Bitmap ArrayOfPassedDataGoesHere);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the very least, one issue is that you need to declare the constructor to accept an array of images. So you need:

```
public Form2(Bitmap[] ArrayOfPassedDataGoesHere);
```

Try that and see if it works!

*Note* - One other observation is you don't need to initialize the member variable until you are in the constructor. So the following code will work fine (in "Form2"):

```
private readonly Bitmap []myForm2Bitmaps;

public Form2(Bitmap[] passedImages) {
   myForm2Bitmaps = passedImages;
   // any other init code here
}
```

The "readonly" keyword allows you to initialize the array in the constructor and not change it after that. This is useful for variables that don't need to change (which might be the case here?)

Comment: It worked! Thanks, I got it wrong coz I made this one "Public Form2(Bitmap[] ArrayOfDataToBePassed = new Bitmap[size])"

Comment: and for your note, that's the way I do it. It's just to shorten my post. but thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

`Form2` needs to have `Bitmap[]` in its constructor to receive an array.

Better would be for the constructor to accept `Enumerator<Bitmap>`, so as to be agnostic about exactly how the incoming data is stored (maybe you'll download it from the web, relatively slowly), and then store it however is appropo for your class's needs.